# Is the word "prose" singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I understand that generally "prose" is used as a mass noun so it should be treated as a singular noun. However, in this context, "is" sounds odd to me. Is my intuition leading me astray?

> On the whole her prose are understandable.

or

> On the whole her prose is understandable.

Note: This is in reference to a single book so proses seems out of place (and sounds awkward anyway).

Comment: Yes, your intuition is leading you astray.  "... prose is..." is clearly the way to go; *prose* does not violate mass-noun rules.

Comment: It's a mass noun. The concepts of singular and plural don't apply (think *water*).

Comment: A mass uncountable noun, no less. How many prose do you have? ;)

Comment: To become countable, and subject to rules of singular and plural, it has to become *a piece of prose* - just like *poetry* or *music*.

Comment: But if earlier I'm referring to a particular sentence, does that mean that I'm breaking the book down into pieces of prose?

Comment: Eg: "Some of the author's sentences are oddly written and hard to follow (e.g. “Even when we’re anonymous and the group not particularly desirable, we’d still like to be included more than not — and it hurts when we are excluded.”), but on the whole her prose are understandable."

Comment: I would still say "on the whole her prose is understandable." Mass uncountable nouns use singular. To wit: although nonsensical you could say "on the whole her milk is understandable" or "on the whole her sand is understandable" and it would be grammatically correct; if you said "are" it wouldn't be.

Comment: Maybe we can backform a new singular *pro* just as *pea* developed from the mass noun *pease.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your intuition is leading you astray. Prose is the form of the language she is using, like poetry, or verse, or music. Poetry is understandable, verse is understandable, music is understandable, prose is understandable.

The confusion might come because the sound at the end of the word prose is also often used at the end of plural nouns. The same is true of nose and rose. His nose is red. The rose is yellow. Her prose is purple, but understandable.